# aws lamda springboot proxy gateway API response results in bad request

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-api-gateway

I followed https://www.danvega.dev/blog/aws-lambda-spring-boot-3 and deployed a springboot REST endpoint

[image: LamdaHandler]
[image: API gateway - proxy]
[image]
[image]
(0448af16-759f-44cf-bbaa-2f324eb773f8) Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 5198 ms
(0448af16-759f-44cf-bbaa-2f324eb773f8) Endpoint response body before transformations: [Binary Data]
(0448af16-759f-44cf-bbaa-2f324eb773f8) Method response body after transformations: {
"timestamp": "2024-01-02T04:59:00.584+00:00",
"path": "/api/v1/detect-text",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"requestId": "34d480b9"
}

I am not sure why it fails with 400 in transforming the response

Comment: @PostMapping(value="detect-text", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 @ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity<DetectDocumentTextResult> detectText(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)throws Exception {
  System.out.println("Received request .......");
  var response  = service.detectText(file.getInputStream());
  System.out.println("Sending response ......");
  return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
 }